# Angular 2: How to propagate HTML elements with router?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, router-outlet

There's a basic DOM:

```
main
- child A        :goBack()
  -- subChild A  :*
- child B        :goBack()
```

From the `app.component.html` I propagate a `footer` element to all DOM children.
What I wonder is, why does the `Back` button not appear on the subchild A page?

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kt1yzo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Why would it appear? It's not in the app component's template, and it's not in the subchild component's template, which are the only components being displayed. subchild is badly named: it's not a child component of child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create subchild as an actual child route. Otherwise it will be handled as any other route and completely replace the `<router-outlet>` tag, in this case the `ChildComponent`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent },
  {
    path: ':child', component: ChildComponent, children: [
      { path: 'subChildA', component: SubChildComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

Also, you need a second `<router-outlet>` tag within the template of your `ChildComponent` where the subroutes (subchildren) are supposed to be rendered.

Have a look at the modified [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvu7o?embed=1&file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts).

Comment: Totally! Route children are not part of the Heroes tutorial, so didn't learn about it until now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create child route for that. Check this edit

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oupmd9

specially **app-routing.module.ts**

Comment: This is almost correct, but you are missing a second `<router-outlet>` tag in the `ChildComponent` to render the subroutes. Also, you would render the ChildComponent twice on `/childA` because of the nested `{ path: '', component: ChildComponent }`. This should be removed. It's always good to add the essential code snippets of your solution because links like stackblitz might break in the future.